# Vertical Spacing Issues in Beamer

Tags: beamer, spacing

A few questions on here have already attempted to address this, but I am yet to find a satisfactory answer. I have the following document and would like to perfectly vertically centre the text in each slide. However, it still seems that there is a small amount more spacing above the text than below. What is causing this and what can be done to fix it (not manually)? See the image below for the issue. [image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{c}[true]{% centered
  \beamer@frametopskip=0pt plus 1fill\relax%
  \beamer@framebottomskip=0pt plus 1fill\relax%
    \beamer@frametopskipautobreak=\beamer@frametopskip\relax%
    \beamer@framebottomskipautobreak=\beamer@framebottomskip\relax%
  \def\beamer@initfirstlineunskip{}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.0}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[c]{}
Hello world!
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[c]{title}
Hello world!
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The centre of the text seems to be in the centre of the page https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnyT5.png

Comment: (quick hack to show the frame centre: `\usepackage{tikz}
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,thick,red]
\draw (current page.east) -- (current page.west);
\draw (current page.north east) -- (current page.south west);
\draw (current page.south east) -- (current page.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}
}`)

Comment: Can you a) confirm that you get the same alignment as in https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnyT5.png and b) clarify what alignment you would like instead?

Comment: Equal space measure from where? Baseline? Centre of the line?

Comment: Not sure why this has been marked for closure, considering similar questions haven't addressed this issue at all. See the image I provided above. I want no space between the top box and the Hello.

Comment: Use a text with de- and ascenders instead?

Comment: For me the issue is rather clear, it asks to center the visible bounding box of the text, which in this case would be equal to the horizontal bar of the H for example. Voting to leave open.

Comment: Thank you, Marijn. It's a common issue with beamer, I think. I'm sure this isn't an issue with article, or at least not one I've noticed.

Comment: @wrb98 With `article` class: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ryvQ.png